# Ajax on success displace divs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have ajax function:

**In the html file I have something like:**

```
<div id="datos98" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="datos99" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="usuario">
    <table id="rowed2"></table>
    <div id="prowed2"></div>
</div>
<script src="rowedex2.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

**In some point of my js file I have a ajax function like this:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'server2.php',
    data: &ciudadh=juan&corporacionh=&radicado=&ultima=&anotaciones=&oper=addf&id='+allRows+'',

    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#mensaje5').show().html('<br><br><h2>Por favor  espere....<br><img src="c.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="cargando" border="0">');
    },

    success: function (data){
        $('#datos99').html(data);
    },

    complete: function(){
        $('#datos99').show();
    }
});
```

The function is fine, but when this function have success the data is loaded on this

```
<div id="datos99" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

But the data is too long so I need that this div displace the others divs at the bottom (below of the `datos99` div). so can read all the information (Data ajax loaded and the data that it was stay here before).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information to pinpoint the problem. Div's normally expand to fit their content. What styles do you have defined for your divs? Is anything positioned absolute of fixed? Does anything have a fixed or max height? How are they not displacing? Do they overlap? Does the div get bigger at all? Is the content just hidden? Does a scrollbar appear?

Comment: like Patrick said, once the data has been loaded to your div that should have automatically expanded to fit the content thereby displacing the other elements below it.

Comment: As patrick and keith said look at styles given to that div

Comment: thanks for your comments. But that no happen because the div that I need for displacing have a css rule into one specifuc position like this: position: absolute;  top: 320px; left: 25px; width: 674px;
padding: 50px; height: 900px;  so this div mantein the css rule position and don't move to anywhere.

Comment: just try position:relative;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code with this

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url : 'server2.php',
data: 'ciudadh=juan&corporacionh=&radicado=&ultima=&anotaciones=&oper=addf&id='+allRows,

beforeSend: function(){
    $('#mensaje5').show().html('<br><br><h2>Por favor  espere....<br><img src="c.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="cargando" border="0">');
},

success: function (data){
    $('#datos99').html(data);
}
 }).complete(function(){
    $('#datos99').show();
 });
```

or to this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url : 'server2.php',
data: 'ciudadh=juan&corporacionh=&radicado=&ultima=&anotaciones=&oper=addf&id='+allRows,

beforeSend: function(){
    $('#mensaje5').show().html('<br><br><h2>Por favor  espere....<br><img src="c.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="cargando" border="0">');
},

success: function (data){
    $('#datos99').html(data);
     $('#datos99').show();
}, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't that clear, but I'll take a stab at it.  If I'm understanding your problem, I think your issue has to do with the fact that you're assigning `<div id="datos99">` with a fixed height of 900px.  Therefore, when it's populated with the data returned from the ajax call, it is messesing up your layout.  This happens because the data returned is too big to fit in the div.

You can solve this by adding `overflow: auto` to your CSS for `<div id="datos99">`.  This will allow your ajax data to fit nicely in the div and provide a scroll bar if the data is larger than your div's height

**CSS:**

```
#datos99 {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 320px; 
    left: 25px; 
    width: 674px; 
    padding: 50px; 
    height: 900px;
    overflow: auto;
 }
```

P.S You should edit your question and provide more information.  It will help us answer your question better.  I would also adjust your question and state your problem more clearly.